# Apache Directory Studio java was started but returned exit code=13

Tags: java, apache, apache-directory

I have to install **Apache Directory Studio**.

For this I perform the below Steps

1. Download ApacheDirectoryStudio-win32-x86-2.0.0.v20130628.exe
2. Double click on ApacheDirectoryStudio-win32-x86-2.0.0.v20130628.exe and perform Next than it ask for Java Home Directory
3. I browse and give the path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\ on Java Home Directory and perform Next Steps as Default Configuration

After complete installation of Apache Directory Studio when I try to Open Apache Directory Studio it gives the following Error

[image]

I am using Java 1.8 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has been resolved.

The issue is that, my "Apache Directory Studio" is `64bit` and my "jdk" is `32bit`.
So I just uninstalled the jdk `32bit` and installed jdk `64bit`, after this issue has been fixed.

Thanks everyone for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Just to complement, you have to install the JRE and JDK.

Answer (score 20):

Apache Directory Studio requires the JDK and will show that error when it tries to run on a normal JRE.

Find the ApacheDirectoryStudio.ini file in the application root (e.g., in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Directory Studio")

Add or update these 2 lines in the INI ['C:\Program Files\Apache Directory Studio\Apache Directory Studio.ini'] (adjust the JDK path according to your setup):

---

- -vm
- C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin

---

Answer (score 5):

Apache Directory Studio
Edit the configuration file for ADS. Mine was here

```
C:\Apache Directory Studio\ApacheDirectoryStudio\ApacheDirectoryStudio
```

Take a backup of the file before editing it.

Add the following lines to the bottom of the file and save it.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\javaw.exe
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Works now :)

The same technique also works for Eclipse. Just edit the eclipse configuration file in the same way. Mine was here: -

```
C:\Eclipse\eclipse\eclipse
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I'm on Win10 x64 and doesn't use Eclipse, don't know if that has anything to do with it though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the second line in the error dialog screenshot, it shows the path that it is looking for the javaw.exe file. It is C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath.

If you browse to this directory you'll se that it contains three shortcuts to java.exe, javaw.exe and javas.exe. Make sure that these shortcuts are pointing to valid exe files. If not delete these shortcuts and create new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to uninstall the 64bit Apache Directory version and to install the 32bit version, or vice versa if your first setup was the 32bit version.

Here is the windows download page for reference 
http://directory.apache.org/studio/download/download-windows.html